# Remove \t from a list of lists

Tags: python, string

I would like to remove the `\t` from the second token.
Was trying something with loops but was not successful. Any help please?

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'[\t]')
for sent in train_sents:
    for tuples in sent:
         print tuples[1]

 [('O', 'Identification\t'),
 ('O', 'of\t'),
 ('O', 'APC2,\t'),
 ('O', 'a\t'),
 ('O', 'homologue\t'),
 ('O', 'of\t'),
 ('O', 'the\t'),
 ('B-DISEASE', 'adenomatous\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', 'polyposis\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', 'coli\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', 'tumour\t'),
 ('O', 'suppressor\t'),
 ('O', '.\t')],
 [('O', 'The\t'),
 ('B-DISEASE', 'adenomatous\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', 'polyposis\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', 'coli\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', '(\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', 'APC\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', ')\t'),
 ('I-DISEASE', 'tumour\t'),
 ('O', '-suppressor\t'),
 ('O', 'protein\t'),
 ('O', 'controls\t'),
 ('O', 'the\t'),
 ('O', 'Wnt\t'),
 ('O', 'signalling\t'),
 ('O', 'pathway\t'),
 ('O', 'by\t'),
 ('O', 'forming\t'),
 ('O', 'a\t'),
 ('O', 'complex\t'),
 ('O', 'with\t'),
 ('O', 'glycogen\t'),
 ('O', 'synthase\t'),
 ('O', 'kinase\t'),
 ('O', '3beta\t'),
 ('O', '(\t'),
 ('O', 'GSK-3beta\t'),
 ('O', ')\t'),
 ('O', ',\t'),
 ('O', 'axin\t'),
 ('O', '/\t'),
 ('O', 'conductin\t'),
 ('O', 'and\t'),
 ('O', 'betacatenin\t'),
 ('O', '.\t')]
```

Comment: use [strip](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html) function, `[tuples[1].rstrip("\t") for tuples in sent]`

Comment: “Was trying something with loops but was not successful” is not something that can be debugged. Your code is probably close to working, and we could show you how to make it work if we could see it, but without seeing it there’s not much to do except write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` should be useful here.See below:

```
 lst=[('O', 'signalling\t'),('O', 'kinase\t'),('try_yourself_first','happy_coding\t')]
 for tup,i in zip (lst,range(0,len(lst))):
    lst[i]=(tup[0],tup[1].replace('\t',''))
 print(lst)
```

OUTPUT:

```
 [('O', 'signalling'), ('O', 'kinase'), ('try_yourself_first', 'happy_coding')]
```